# How to wrap an equation while aligning the equal sign?

Tags: amsmath

The equation exceed the margin, and I want to wrap the  equation while aligning the equal sign, the following is my original codes:

```
 \begin{eqnarray}\label{ 7}
  \begin{split}
  \beta_{ij}^{js-js}\mid z_{ij}  &=  \left(1 -\left(\frac{n -2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}+\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4}} +\frac{\text{p}-2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2}  -\frac{\left(n -2\right)\left(\text{p}-2\right)}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2 \left(\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}+\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4}\right)} \right)z_{ij} 
    \\&=\left(1 -\left(\frac{n -2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j} +\frac{\text{p}-2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2} - \frac{\left(n -2\right)\left(\text{p}-2\right)}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2 \left(\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j\right)} \right)\right) z_{ij} 
    \end{split}
    \end{eqnarray}
```

[image: pic]

The result that I want

[image]

I tried `\right\\ \left` before the cutting position, but I didn't get the desire result. I also try the following solution I checked online, but still not work in my case. Could anyone offer me a help? Thank you.

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
 y & = & x \\
& & {} + x1 \\
& & {} + x2
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: You should never use `eqnarray` it is completely obsoleted by the `amsmath` package which you must also have loaded as you have `split` defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `equation` and `\begin{aligned}[b]` (as @Mico kindly suggested), this is under the assumption you want only a single number for the equation. With the `[b]` option the eqn number is printed on the bottom line

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
  \beta_{ij}^{js-js}\mid z_{ij}  &=
    \Biggl(1 -\Biggl(\frac{n -2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j} \rVert^2 - \frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}+\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4} } + 
    \frac{\mathrm{p}-2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2} \\
     &\qquad-\frac{(n -2)(\mathrm{p}-2)}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2 \Bigl(\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2  -\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}+\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4}\Bigr)} \Biggr)  \Biggr) z_{ij}
    \\
    &=\biggl(1 -\biggl(\frac{n -2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j} +\frac{\text{p}-2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2} - \frac{(n -2)(\mathrm{p}-2)}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2 (\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j)} \biggr)\biggr) z_{ij} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

What I did, except using the aforementioned environment is:

1. aligned the second row with a `\qquad` space, in order to give it an "indent", which is what I think you wanted
2. Got rid of `left` and `right` which were abused (it's best to manually scale the parentheses with commands such as `bigl`–`bigr` and so on, to have better spacing and scaling). you could tweak it if you want
3. I replaced `text` with `mathrm` (text gives the current font)

Comment: It seems kind of odd to place the equation number on the middle line. Consider replacing the `split` environment with an `aligned[b]` environment?

Comment: @Mico if I manage to correct it I'll do it now thanks, you're right

Comment: Congrats on passing the 4K rep mark!

Comment: there's a closing parenthesis missing in the first equation, and the initial paren in the same equation should be larger, the same size as the one preceding the fraction.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'll try and correct this as soon as I come home from work, which will be in around 12 hours, thanks

Comment: @Mico right, thank you, I'm at work and did it quickly, now it's ok, I guess

Answer (score 6):

Never use `eqnarray`.

With some simplifications and changes in the input, notably

- `\norm{...}` instead of `\lVert...\rVert`
- `\bm` instead of `\boldsymbol`; also `\bm{z_j}` and similar have been changed to `\bm{z}_j` because the subscript should not be bold
- `\text{p}` became `p`; if you really need it upright, it should be `\mathrm{p}`
- the complicated denominator in the third summand in the top equation has been set as a product
- useless `\left` and `\right` removed
- some `\,` for spacing the big parentheses added

I left `\label{7}`, although I suggest a more meaningful name. In any case `\label{ 7}` is dubious, as it requires `\ref{ 7}` which is awkward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,bm}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{7}
\begin{split}
\beta_{ij}^{js-js}\mid z_{ij}  
  &=\Biggl(
    1-\Biggl(\,\frac{n-2}{
                 \norm{\bm{z}_j}^2-
                 \frac{2(n-2)\sum_i z_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z}_{i}}^2}+
                 \frac{(n-2)^2\sum_i Z_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z}_i}^4}
               }+
               \frac{p-2}{\norm{\bm{z}_{i}}^2}
  \\
  &
   \hphantom{{}=\Biggl(1}-
               \frac{1}{\norm{\bm{z}_i}^2}
               \frac{(n-2)(p-2)}{
                 \norm{\bm{z}_j}^2-\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z}_{i}}^2}+
                 \frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z}_i}^4}
               }
         \,\Biggr)\Biggr)z_{ij}
  \\[2ex]
  &=\biggl(
    1-\biggl(\,
        \frac{n-2}{\norm{\bm{z}_j}^2-k_j}+
        \frac{p-2}{\norm{\bm{z}_{i}}^2}-
        \frac{(n-2)(p-2)}{\norm{\bm{z}_{i}}^2 (\norm{\bm{z}_j}^2-k_j)}
      \,\biggr)
    \biggr) z_{ij} 
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I replaced `eqnarray` by `align` and adjusted some of the markup. (the use of `\boldsymbol` still looks a bit suspect.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{align}\label{zz}% don't use numbers as labels.
  \beta_{ij}^{js-js}\mid z_{ij}  &= \Bigl(1 -
\bigl(\frac{n -2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}+\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4}} +\frac{\mathrm{p}-2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2}\notag\\
&\qquad
  -\frac{(n -2)(\mathrm{p}-2)}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2 (\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}+\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4})}
\bigr)z_{ij} 
    \\&=(1 -(\frac{n -2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j} +\frac{\mathrm{p}-2}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2} - \frac{(n -2)(\mathrm{p}-2)}{\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2 (\lVert \boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j)} )
\Bigr) z_{ij} 
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever else you do, don't use `eqnarray` -- it's badly deprecated.

I suggest using a single `align` environment, not using a `split` environment, replacing all `\boldsymbol` directives with `\bm` (from the `bm` package), and defining a `\norm` macro to cut down on all the `\lVert` and `\rVert` directives. For extra legibility, consider using square brackets in addition to round parentheses. And, rather than `\text{p}`, write `\mathrm{p}`, and don't overuse `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\beta_{ij}^{js-js} \bigm| z_{ij}  
&=  \left[1 -\left(
 \frac{n -2}{\norm{\bm{z_j}}^2
  -\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z_{i}}}^2}
  +\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z_i}}^4}} 
  +\frac{\mathrm{p}-2}{\norm{\bm{z_{i}}}^2} 
  \right.\right. \notag\\
  &\qquad\quad -\left.\left.\frac{(n-2)(\mathrm{p}-2)}{\norm{\bm{z_{i}}}^2
  \Bigl( \norm{\bm{z_j}}^2
  -\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z_{i}}}^2}
  +\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}{\norm{\bm{z_i}}^4} \Bigr)} 
  \right)\!\right] z_{ij}\notag\\[2ex]
&=\biggl[1 -\biggl(\frac{n -2}{\norm{\bm{z_j}}^2-k_j} 
  +\frac{\mathrm{p}-2}{\norm{\bm{z_{i}}}^2} 
  -\frac{(n-2)(\mathrm{p}-2)}{\norm{\bm{z_{i}}}^2 
  (\norm{\bm{z_j}}^2-k_j)} \biggr)\biggr] z_{ij} \label{eq:7}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

with `multlined` from `mathtools` and consider some suggestion from above answers:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}\label{eq:num7}
\beta_{ij}^{js-js}\Big| z_{ij}
    & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\linewidth]
        \left[1 -
        \left(\frac{n -2}
                   {\lVert\boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2
                   -\frac{2(n-2)\sum_iz_{ij}^2}
                         {\lVert\boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}
                   +\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_iZ_{ij}^2}
                         {\lVert\boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4}}
        +\frac{\mathrm{p}-2}
              {\lVert\boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}
        \right.\right.
                                                    \\
        \left.\left.
        -\frac{(n-2)(\mathrm{p}-2)}
              {\lVert\boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2
                \Bigl(\lVert\boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2
                -\frac{2(n-2)\sum_i z_{ij}^2}
                      {\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2}
                +\frac{(n-2)^2\sum_i Z_{ij}^2}
                      {\lVert \boldsymbol{z_i}\rVert^4}
                \Bigr)
              } \right)z_{ij}
        \right]
        \end{multlined}                     \notag  \\[1ex]
    & = \left[(1 -\left(\frac{n - 2}
                            {\lVert\boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j}
            + \frac{\mathrm{p}-2}
                   {\lVert \boldsymbol{z_{i}} \rVert^2}
            - \frac{\left(n -2\right)\left(\mathrm{p}-2\right)}
                   {\lVert\boldsymbol{z_{i}}\rVert^2
                        \left(\lVert\boldsymbol{z_j}\rVert^2-k_j\right)}
            \right)
    \right] z_{ij}

    \end{align}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `\sum\limits`, you should also enlarge quite a few of the parentheses.

Comment: @Mico, you have right, I remove `\limits`.

Comment: the size of the opening bracket and parenthesis in the first line doesn't match the size of the closing parenthesis and bracket on the next line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, yes, they are :( the paranthesis in denomitar are to big, they should be `\Big` instead `\bigg`. corrected.